# Application Error in Event Log

Tags: crash, windows-xp, event-log, vb5

I am frequently getting the following error for a VB5 app in the Event Log:

```
Faulting application [My EXE Name].exe, version 0.0.0.0, faulting module msvbvm50.dll, version 5.2.82.44, fault address 0x000436fb.
```

What could be the cause?  `msvbvm50.dll` is part of the VB5 run-time and I can't think why that would be faulting.  I would have assumed it would be a very reliable component.

Is there anyway to debug the cause of such errors?

Answer (score -1):

According to [this URL](http://localtech.gidblog.com/2011/01/12/windows-vista-windows-7-missing-msvbvm50dll/), msvbvm50.dll does not run anymore on Vista and 7. Try the steps they mention.

Comment: `msvbvm50.dll` is installed on the machine otherwise the app wouldn't run at all.